# Integrations are equivalent?

Tags: calculus

> $$\tag{1} \int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{1+\cos^2(t)} \ dt .$$

Which of the following is numerically different from the integration above?
A) $$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1+\cos^2(t)}\ dt  $$
B) $$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1+\sin^2(t)} \ dt $$ 
C) $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{1+\sin^2(t)} \ dt   $$
D) $$2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1+\cos^2(2t)}\ dt  $$
E) $$2\int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{1+\cos^2(2t)}\ dt $$

I use the graph of sine and cosine, and get A), B), C) are the same as (1)
and by applying substitution, D) is also the same as (1)

HOWEVER, the result I got by hand is different from what I used calculator to double check my answer. The calculator told me D) is different from (1). Could anyone help me where went wrong? and how to do this problem without calculator? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Put $t-\frac\pi2=u, dt=du$

$$\int_0^\pi  f(\cos ^2t)dt=\int_{-\frac\pi2}^\frac\pi2f(\cos^2\left(\frac\pi2+u\right)) du=\int_{-\frac\pi2}^\frac\pi2f(\sin^2u)du$$

as $\cos\left(\frac\pi2+u\right)=-\sin u$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1+\cos^2(2t)}\ dt \\
\overset{x=2t}{=}&2\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1+\cos^2(x)}\ dx \\
=&\int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{1+\cos^2(x)}\ dx
\end{align}

Note the upper limit of the integral. That's because $t=\frac{x}{2}$, so $t$ in $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ is the same as $x$ in $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: yes!! this is what I have to conclude (D) is the same as (1)

Comment: @Lily then it is. Actually I tried it with Mathematica, they give the same result.